# Если с сайта №1 делаю запрос на сайт №2(где авторизирован я) - почему я на сайте№1 получаю новую сессию?

Tags: php, csrf

Вот такой вопрос интересует, если данные сессии - мы получаем от значения куки PHPSESSID, то как работает схема, что когда я с сайта №1 отправляю запрос на сайт №2 (на сайте №2 я авторизирован, есть PHPSESSID) - но для сайта №1 - создается новая сессия, чистая... Почему так работает, если я делаю запрос от авторизированного юзера?

```
// Сайт №1
$r = file_get_contents('http://site2.ru?action=getSessionData');
var_dump($r);// Получаю чистую сессию!


// Cайт №2, здесь пользователь авторизирован, и если пользователь 
// перейдет прямо по ссылке http://site2.ru?action=getSessionData 
// То ему покажет данные сессии
if( $_GET['action'] == 'getSessionData') print_r($_SESSION);
```

Почему при таком запросе с сайта№1 - создается новая сессия?

По идее должно же быть отображение данных от "авторизированного пользователя".

Comment: Уточните, что значит для "сайта №1 создаётся новая сессия" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не понимаете как работает механизм сессий. Следите за мыслью.

Когда вы на сервере с IP = 1.2.3.4 выполняете код file_get_context -- то вы получаете сессию. Но почему вы решили, что ваш домашний компьютер, у которого совершенно другой IP адрес, скажем IP = 3.4.5.6 должен будет показать вам чью-то чужую сессию? Это совершенно другая сессия для другого компьютера!

Вы бы не захотели, чтобы ваша сессия кому-то другому уплыла? Нет. Ну вот она никуда и не уплыла.

Если понятно, то попробуем чуть глубже посмотреть.

В общем-то вашему сайту site2.ru (в дефолтном механизме сессий, не привязываемых к IP) глубоко фиолетово, какой IP-адрес.

Сессии идентифицируются либо по GET-параметру, либо по кукисам. Вы можете посмотреть сессию украв идентификатор сессии и подставив его в в ваш URL -- но вы не показали такую ссылку, поэтому и сессия другая.
Вы могли бы сохранить в первом запросе ответ, прочитать проставленную куку и предьявить её -- но вы не сделали и этого.

Итого, это по всем статьям другая сессия.

Из примеров могу вспомнить форум PHPBB дремучих версий, в котором в поисковике выдавалась каждый раз новая ссылка (с идентификатором сессий) и был даже специальный фикс для этого.

Ну и посмотрите код разных авторизаций на чужих сайтах -- ведь куки сохраняют и предъявляют именно для этого.

В принципе, на этом ответ можно и закончить. Если же всё написанное вы понимаете, то видимо вы плохо сформулировали вопрос, не объяснив важные вещи касательно сайтов 1 и 2, вашего кода и того, как вы нестандартно модифицировали сессии.

Comment: То есть, если при авторизации пользователь - получает в сессию $_SESSION['CSRF_TOKEN'] - то от csrf - защита готова? Я просто видел в уроках, что делают при каждом обновлении страницы - новый токен, но тут проблема, если открыть несколько вкладок сайта - то на старых страницах токены будут неактуальны.